# How to change the color of a progress bar

Tags: html, css, fonts, progress-bar

I want to change the color of the **last update text**, by default it is black , is there a way to introduce some code to change the text color as i made for the bar text? Help me to introduce the code that is missing.

```
<div id="progress">
    <span id="percent">2%</span>
    <div id="bar"></div>
    </div>
Last updated: 7/01/2013
#progress{
 width: 500px;   
 border: 1px solid orange;
 position: relative;
 padding: 1px;
}

#percent {
 position: absolute;   
 left: 50%;
 color:#C3B004; 
}

#bar {
 height: 20px;
 background-color:#2CB032;
 width: 2%;
}
```

Here is the link for the bar : [link](http://jsfiddle.net/WawPr/)

Comment: And what's the HTML and CSS for the element containing the `'Last updated'` text? The `#progress` element itself has no relevance to the question you're asking.

Comment: You don't provide any reference on where the 'Last updated' text is coming from. Are you generating it? Is code generating it? Does it contain any HTML in source? Specifics, please.

Comment: It was my mistake ... here is the html code : <div id="progress">
    <span id="percent">2%</span>
    <div id="bar"></div>
    </div>
<tr>
        <td>Last updated: 7/01/2013</td>

Comment: how to change the size, colour and font of the last updated text ? is there a code that i need to introduce ? please help

Comment: If that's your html, then it's invalid: the only element that can be a sibling of a `tr` element is another `tr`.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you can wrap the `Last updated: 7/01/2013` in `<span>` tags, and give it a class, then you can style it however you want.

```
<span class="updated">Last updated: 7/01/2013</span>
```

CSS:

```
.updated {
    font-size: 12px;    //size
    color: green;       //colour
    font-family:"Arial" //font 
}
```