# How to change the background colour of a progress bar

Tags: javascript, html, css, progress-bar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change the color of a progress bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14164174/how-to-change-the-color-of-a-progress-bar)

I have done a simple progress bar, but i dont know how to change the background color of the bar, the percentage color and the text " Last updated " colour .. Is there a code that should be introduced  ? Please help me with some code/demo examples . Thanks

HTML:

```
  <table>
    <tr>
        <td>Last updated 1/4/2013:</td>
        <td><div class="progress" data-value="0"><span>0%</span></div></td>
    </tr>
```

CSS:

```
.progress.ui-progressbar {position:relative;height:2em;}
.progress span {position:static;margin-top:-2em;text-align:center;display:block;line-height:2em;padding-left:200px;padding-right:200px;}
.progress[aria-valuenow="0"] 
span {margin-top:0px;}​
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".progress").each(function() {
        var progressValue = $(this).data("value");
        $(this).progressbar({
            value: progressValue
        }).children("span").appendTo(this);
    });
});​
```

Comment: How is this question different from the last question you asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14164174/how-to-change-the-color-of-a-progress-bar?

Answer (score 1):

To change the background color of the percentage bar add this CSS rule:

```
.progress {
  color: red;
}
```

For the text color:

I would recommend first adding an `<h1>` tag around the title so it looks like this:

```
<td><h1>Last updated 1/4/2013:</h1></td>
```

Then add this CSS rule:

```
td h1 {
  color: red;
}
```

And to change the percentage color add this rule:

```
.progress span {
  color: blue;
}
```

Also, close your `<table>` tag.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the background and the grey think doesnt change ... Some ideeas ?